# CiviCRM (on WordPress) runs too slow to be useful

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

Just installed WordPress and then CiviCRM on my Hostmonster.com hosted website.  CiviCRM runs too slow to be useful.  Is there w way to make it run without 1-2 minutes for each option selected, with timeout errors (504).  Is there a fix?

Comment: Is there a better engine than WordPress that I should consider to get better performance from CiviCRM?

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't WordPress, but Hostmonster.  Shared hosting makes its money on sites that don't need any CPU or memory - simple WordPress sites, for instance.

CiviCRM is a much more resource-intensive program than your typical CMS (like WordPress).  If you have *good* shared hosting - which is hard to come by! - then you can sometimes run a very small CiviCRM instance.  Say, 500 contacts.

Consider a VPS instead.  Hostmonster offers a VPS service, but there are cheaper VPS vendors available.  If you're committed to shared hosting, there's a [list of hosting providers](https://civicrm.org/hosting-providers) available - but if you have the resources to support a VPS, you'll be much happier.

Comment: To make it explicit - I've run CiviCRM on WordPress, Drupal, Backdrop, and even a little bit of Joomla.  While you can have a badly configured slow site with any CMS, I've never considered one over another based on performance.

Answer (score 3):

Upon advice from Jon G, I moved from Hostmonster to Siteground hosting.  CiviCRM runs great, now.  Thanks for the assist!   Tom R